# How to configure Apache for XAMPP on Mac OS X Lion to use mod_rewrite?

Tags: macos, mac, apache, webserver

I am totally newbie when it comes to .htaccess or Apache. I don't know how it works.

My URLs are like `http://localhost/category.php?category=something` and I'd like to get the variable value as ***something*** in `category.php` but I'd like to show the URL as `http://localhost/something`

How can I do this? Please help.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this exact string but in your htaccess file you can try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)category=([^&]+)(&.*)?$ [NC]

 RewriteRule ^category\.php$ /%2? [R=301,L]
```

How familiar are you with regular expressions?  That's probably the biggest hurdle to get over with mod_rewrite.

This particular version is intended to work for multiple parameters (optionally) and category can be first or not first.   The other parameters if present are just discarded -- they still sent to your php code, just don't appear in URL.